# Advanced hierarchy in PowerPivot

Tags: hierarchy, powerpivot, dax

I am building a hierarchy in PowerPivot and have an issue that I want to solve.

The hierarchy has 6 levels and view 4 columns of data. The two lowest levels is ordernumber and product groups (on the ordernumber).

Issue:

When viewing the the order number level (level 5), the values should show the full order value, even though some product groups are filter out.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: We need more info on the problem in order to help you, so post the code with which you are having problems. Also, no homework allowed!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this isn't a particularly well written question but I think I know what you are trying to do.

Lets say you have a table called 'SalesData' with columns; Order_Number, Product_Category, Product_Code and Sales.

The following measure would allow you to slice your data by Product_Category and see sales for all transactions that contained a product in that category:

```
=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'SalesData'[Sales] ),
    ALL ( 'SalesData'[Product_Category], 'SalesData'[Product_Code] ),
    VALUES ( 'SalesData'[Order_Number] )
)
```

Effectively what it does is opens up the product stuff so that the result isn't restricted to the thing you have sliced on but then filters your SUM() by a list of the order_ids that were included in the original selection.

Post back more details of your specific case and I can try and tighten it up....

Comment: Sorry that the question is not well defined, DAX is still new to me. This also Means, that I don't know where to wirte the gode suggested. Is it in a cloumn I add to my datasheet?

Comment: This is a measure (known as a calculated field in 2013). The easiest way is to click on 'New Measure' on the PowerPivot tab on the ribbon.